# Conditional Expected Value for uniformly distributed variable

Tags: probability

I am looking for:
$$ E[\theta | r(\theta) \le w ] $$
where $\theta$ is distributed uniformly on [0,2] and $r(\theta)  = \alpha \theta$ , for some unspecified $\alpha < 1$ and some positive w. 
My textbook tells me that the solution to this expected value is E=$(w/2\alpha)$.

While looking for ways of calculating conditional expected values, I stumbled upon a formula where you needed to calculate an integral, and indeed by experimenting a little bit with the formulas, this one gives the correct solution of $\theta = (w/2\alpha)$:

$$ \int_0^2 \alpha \theta  d \theta= w $$

However, I am uncertain whether this is just a coincidence, so I am looking for a general solution to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\Theta\mid\alpha\Theta\leq w) ~=~& \dfrac{\int\limits_0^{\min(w/\alpha,2)} \theta~f_\Theta(\theta)\operatorname d\theta}{\int\limits_0^{\min(w/\alpha,2)} f_\Theta(\theta)\operatorname d\theta}
\\[1ex] =~& \dfrac{\tfrac  1 2\int\limits_0^{\min(w/\alpha,2)} \theta\operatorname d\theta}{\tfrac  1 2\int\limits_0^{\min(w/\alpha,2)} 1\operatorname d\theta} \\[1ex] =~& \tfrac 1 2 \min(w/\alpha,2) \\[1ex] =~&\begin{cases}w/2\alpha & : w< 2\alpha \\[0.5ex] 1 & :2\alpha\leq w\end{cases}\end{align}$$

---

A quicker way to arrive at this is to observe that if $\Theta~\sim~\mathcal U[0;2]$ then $\Theta\vert\Theta{\leq}w/\alpha ~\sim~\mathcal U[0;w/\alpha]$ whenever $0<w<2\alpha$.

$$\mathsf E(\Theta\mid\Theta\leq w/\alpha) ~=~\int_0^{\min(w/\alpha, 2)}\frac \theta{\min(w/\alpha,2)}\operatorname d\theta$$

Comment: Thanks for the very precise answer!
Just one further question: In the second part of your answer, why do you take the integral from zero to min(w/$\alpha$,w)?

Comment: @TartanLeaves  Typo.    $$\int_0^{\min(w/\alpha,2)} \theta/(w/\alpha)\operatorname d \theta ~=~ \min(\frac{w}{2\alpha},1)$$

Comment: That way it works. Thanks!